# Regex to separate all capital words from words that start with capitals

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string:

```
ONE TWO Three Four
```

What regex would give me:

```
ONE TWO | Three Four
```

where | separates a match?

I need the regex string to essentially separate the ALL-CAPITAL words from the words that start with a captial letter

**Edit**:
Assume that the words that are all capital always occur before the words that start with a capital letter.
Also assume that all words will only contain letter a-z, and may have a hyphen in them

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _separate_? Are the all-capital letters always at the start, and are they always followed by the words that only start with a capital letter?

Comment: Separate as in All of the words that are capital should be considered one match, and the words that start with a capital should be a separate match. Yes, it can be assumed that the CAPITAL words will always be before the words that start with capitals

Comment: also: are the characters guaranteed to be ASCII characters? What else can appear in the string apart from the two kind of "words" that you described? Can numbers appear (in the words)? Can punctuation characters appear (in the words)?

Comment: @WalterTross no numbers can appear in the words, but a hyphen (-) can occur

Comment: what about words consisting of a single capital letter?

Comment: @WalterTross For each word containing a single capital letter, the capital should be at the beginning of the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^([-A-Z]+(?:\s+[-A-Z]+)*)\s+([-A-Z][-a-z]*(?:\s+[-A-Z][-a-z]*)*)$')

match = regex.match('ABC D-E-F Ghi J-k-l')
groups = match.groups()
print(groups)
# output:
# ('ABC D-E-F', 'Ghi J-k-l')
```